# os.Mkdir GoLang

Tags: linux, golang

Необходимо в Debian создать директорию и в ней текстовые файлы используя GoLang, для этого написал такую программу:

```
package main

import(
 "os"
 "log"
)

func main(){
                err := os.Mkdir("/home/log_mail/", 0644)
        if err != nil {
                log.Printf("%v", err)
        }

        _,err = os.Create("/home/log_mail/log_main.txt")
        if err != nil {
                log.Printf("%v", err)
        }
}
```

Программа корректно работает только при запуске из под рута, что ни есть хорошо
При обычном запуске, вылезают ошибки

> $ go run main.go
>
> 2018/08/02 11:11:37 mkdir /home/log_mail/: permission denied
>
> 2018/08/02 11:11:37 open /home/log_mail/log_main.txt: no such file or directory

Comment: А у юзера, под которым запускаете, есть права на это? Простой `mkdir` в консоли проходит?

Comment: Все, спасибо, чет совсем не внимателен

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
package main

import(
 "os"
 "log"
)

func main(){
                err := os.MkdirAll("/home/log_mail/", 0750)
        if err != nil {
                log.Printf("%v", err)
        }

        _,err = os.Create("/home/log_mail/log_main.txt")
        if err != nil {
                log.Printf("%v", err)
```

}

Кроме того, если речь идёт про логи, то совершенно необходимы флаги создания и открытия CREATE | APPEND и т.п.